# adb shell auto-complete under Windows 7?

Tags: shell, autocomplete, adb

I tried on linux and ash from busybox does auto-complete command line... But under Windows 7 when I press Tab it doesn't work. Any idea to make Windows 7 smart? :) Thanks!

Looks like auto-complete is done, but nothing echoes back after when tab is pressed...

An example:
adb shell

## ls m[press tab]

after tab is pressed, some space characters are shown, but characters that are generated by auto-complete doesn't echo back, then if I press enter, directory mnt is listed which means auto-complete works but echo system has some problem. Right?

## ls m[space][space][space][press enter]

mnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem by recompiling adb under cygwin. :)

Answer (score 6):

I run adb on Win7 sometimes, both under the cmd.exe and Cygwin, and I was frustrated by how *adb shell* handled autocompletion and character echo. I also use adb under OS X and Linux, and in both of those environments the autocompletion and character handling works as I expect. What the problem on Windows seems to be is that *adb shell* is not setting the terminal modes (*stty/termio()* for UNIX-type shells). I came up with the following workaround that seems to work well for Cygwin's bash shell. I don't know Windows well enough to know if there is a similar command to *stty* for cmd.exe:

```
$ stty -icanon -echo -echoe intr ^0 ; adb shell ; stty sane
```

Of course you can put this in a script.

I believe that the reason that recompiling adb under Cygwin fixes this issue (under Cygwin) is because the recompile causes adb to use the *termio()* calls to setup the local terminal modes so that they don't interfere with what you type to the Android shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ADB enhanced Putty

It support auto complete and coloring

[image: ADB enhanced Putty]

you can download it from
[ADB Putty](https://github.com/sztupy/adbputty/downloads)

read more at [ADB enhanced Putty (replacement for "adb shell" command)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803225)

Answer (score 0):

Auto-complete is controlled by the following Registry key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor
Set the value to 9 or 40.

Comment: I tried that and the value is 9 now. I also tried mintty, it doesn't work as well. I wonder if it's a problem of 'Tab' key mapping in Windows systems...

Comment: I am not quite sure because I also tried to ssh a linux host then launch adb, and that works.

Comment: Well, "auto-complete is done, but nothing echoes back", this is the problem now.