# adb shell auto-complete under Windows 7

Tags: android, shell, autocomplete, cygwin, adb

Regarding this post: [adb shell auto-complete under Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831466/adb-shell-auto-complete-under-windows-7?answertab=votes#tab-top)

The owner's answer is: "Solved this problem by recompiling adb under cygwin. :)"

Unfortunately I can't send comments asking him how did he recompiled the adb under cygwin.

So my question is: How could I recompile adb under cygwin to get auto-compete working in adb?

EDIT: I realized that actually cygwin is already auto-completing when I type inside android bash, but the text is not being showed. Weird, isn't? E.g:

```
# ls /data/tem
```

[TAB]

```
# ls/data/tem    | <<<--- the cursor jumps to here
```

[ENTER]

It list all files and folders within **/data/temp** folder.

Comment: you can post a comment on his answer. if you use @[username] replaceing [username] with his name it will even "ping" him and let him know that someone is talking to him. His profile says he was last seen on the site ~7hrs ago so it is a good bet that he is still active on the site, I'd say post a comment and give it a day or two to see if he replies back to you.

Answer (score 6):

You can use ADB enhanced Putty

It support auto complete and coloring

[image: ADB enhanced Putty]

you can download it from
[ADB Putty](https://github.com/sztupy/adbputty/downloads)

Just start it suing the following command-line:

```
adb-putty.exe -adb -P 5037 transport-usb
```

read more at [ADB enhanced Putty (replacement for "adb shell" command)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803225)

Comment: How would I know what the IP address is?

Comment: ip address not needed for adb

Comment: Then what's the host addr for the adb process?

Comment: @Igor, a bit late but the addess is "transport-usb" (from the XDA forum link).

Comment: Still can not auto-complete after `su`

Answer (score 3):

Try  [PuTTY Tray](https://puttytray.goeswhere.com/). Its work for me!

1. connect to the phone via "adb connect ip:port"
2. run Putty Tray, select Adb and click "Open"

PS.
 You can specify device ID in session settings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm (fortunately) not a Windows user but I guess the problem is not in `adb` but in your shell that is not letting some keys (i.e. **TAB**) reach it.

Try this to see if TAB is received by the android shell:

```
adb shell
# printf '%d\n' "'$(dd bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null)"
<type TAB+ENTER>
9
```

If you cannot see **9** (ascii **TAB**) then your problem is in the Windows shell and you could try cygwin `bash` to reproduce the test and see the results.

Comment: Thanks. I followed your tip and 9 was printed. Yet I'm still not able to auto-complete when I'm in device's bash.

Answer (score 0):

Are you mis-understanding the original post? I think that guy is saying he stopped using the Command Prompt and switched to cygwin.

You can make auto complete work in the Windows command prompt as well. Just run `cmd /f` instead of `cmd`. The other post has instructions on how to permanently enable autocomplete.

If you want to use cygwin then focus on trying to get autocomplete to work in cygwin. It's been years since I used cygwin, but I thought it was enabled by default. Maybe you need to turn off case sensitivity? [How to deactivate uppercase check in cygwin folder autocompletion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201900/how-to-deactivate-uppercase-check-in-cygwin-folder-autocompletion)

Regardless which shell you use it will only auto complete folder and file names.

Comment: You're right, I missed the main question in that post.I'm already using Cygwin and the issue I refer in this post is about auto-complete  when I'm using an android's bash via Cygwin.